# 401 Unauthorized on SOAP UI on REST API POST request

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I am new to SOAP UI , but I am getting

```
401 Unauthorized response
```

for Post Request. My Application is VPN based (HTTPS) and I have passed authentication via token or Basic authentication but nothing worked.

[image]

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 19:26:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 172
Connection: keep-alive
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
    <body>
        <center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
        <hr><center>nginx</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

SOAP UI LOGS:

Tue Jul 14 00:56:37 IST 2020:DEBUG:Stale connection check
Tue Jul 14 00:56:37 IST 2020:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Tue Jul 14 00:56:37 IST 2020:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /ace/api/parameters/ HTTP/1.1
Tue Jul 14 00:56:37 IST 2020:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Tue Jul 14 00:56:37 IST 2020:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Tue Jul 14 00:56:37 IST 2020:DEBUG:Target requested authentication
Tue Jul 14 00:56:37 IST 2020:WARN:Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
Tue Jul 14 00:56:38 IST 2020:INFO:Got response for [https://slrs01vb1ddsv03.as.ad.XXX.XXX.com.:Request 1] in 362ms (172 bytes)
Tue Jul 14 00:57:10 IST 2020:DEBUG:Connection closed

Comment: Posting image link is really respectful to the developers and programmers who wish to debug and find the issue alongside you. I suggest you paste relevant information and post the error directly over here. Not only will this help future developers with similar issue but everyone

Comment: Added SOAP UI logs here. Hope this would help